# Object Data Encryption using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object like following

var CareGiverData = new Object();

```
    CareGiverData.firstName = 'abg';  


    CareGiverData.lastName =  'abg';
    CareGiverData.Address1 =  'abg';
    CareGiverData.Address2 =  'abg';
    CareGiverData.City =  'abg';
    CareGiverData.State =  'abg';
    CareGiverData.Zip =  'abg';
    CareGiverData.Phone =  'abg';
    CareGiverData.Email =  'abg';
    CareGiverData.Language =  'abg';
```

i want to encrypt this object data and send it to webservice using json.stringify(data) there i want to decrypt..
Can i encrypt the entire object data using Javascript??
Can any one please suggest me better way

Comment: What's wrong with letting the transport layer handle encryption, i.e. SSL?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219608